# The commutant of a tensor product

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras

In this whole post beginning with the second paragraph, by "tensor product" I will mean the operation done on Von Neumann algebras where one applies the homomorphism from here [Tensor products of maps](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155916/tensor-products-of-maps)
to the algebraic tensor product of the Von Neumann algebras, and then takes the WO closure in the space $B(H \otimes H)$ where that "$\otimes$" is the tensor product of Hilbert spaces in the Hilbert sense.

As part of the proof of some equalities relating the commutant of a tensor product to the tensor product of commutants, I am asked to prove "directly" that if $C(H)$ denotes the scalar operators on $H$, then $(B(H) \otimes C(H))'=C(H) \otimes B(H)$  I am having trouble proving that the left side is included in the right side.  Help please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $\{ e_m\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $H$ and that $\{e_{mn}\}$ are the corresponding matrix units. Suppose that $T \in B(H \otimes H)$ with $$T (e_i \otimes e_j)=\sum_{k,l} T_{ij}^{kl} e_k \otimes e_l.$$ 
We now also assume that $T$ commutes with the operators $\{e_{mn} \otimes \iota\}$ (where $\iota:H \to H$ is the identity map). A direct calculation shows that $T$ must be of the form $\iota \otimes S$.

We have 
$$
T\circ (e_{mn} \otimes \iota) (e_i \otimes e_j) =\delta_{in} \sum_{kl} T_{mj}^{kl}e_k \otimes e_l,
$$
where $\delta_{in}$ is the Kronecker delta function.

On the other hand, we have
$$
(e_{mn} \otimes \iota)\circ T (e_i \otimes e_j)= \delta_{nk} \sum_{kl} T_{ij}^{kl} e_m \otimes e_l=\sum_l T^{nl}_{ij} e_m \otimes e_l.
$$
Comparing these two expressions, we see that $T_{mj}^{kl}$ must be $0$ unless $m=k$. We then have that $\delta_{in} T_{mj}^{ml}=T_{ij}^{nl}$ or $T_{mj}^{ml}=T_{ij}^{il}$. But this says that $T_{mj}^{ml}$ is the same for all $m$. Thus $T=\iota \otimes S$, where $Se_j =\sum_l T_{mj}^{ml}e_l$.

As $\lambda \iota \otimes \frac{S}{\lambda}= \iota \otimes S$ for a nonzero constant $\lambda$, we have shown that $$(B(H) \otimes C(H))'\subseteq C(H) \otimes B(H).$$ The other inclusion is easy.